# What does `var@GOTPCREL(%rip)` mean?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, dynamic-linking, att, got

What does `<some symbol>@GOTPCREL(%rip)` mean?

I've come across this line `mov var@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax` and was a bit puzzled about the weird syntax.

Can someone please recommend the relevant docs I should read to understand this?
Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table

Comment: Possible duplicate: [GOTPCREL(%rip) in GAS Intel syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52879388).  Also related [Why use the Global Offset Table for symbols defined in the shared library itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55587313).  Also semi-related [ELF Shared Object in x86-64 Assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9341212) for when usage of GOT is unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`foo@GOTPCREL(%rip)` is the GOT entry for the symbol `foo`, accessed with a RIP-relative addressing mode.

The GOT entry is filled in by the dynamic linker (supporting symbol interposition), and holds the absolute address of the symbol `foo`, so `mov foo@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax` **loads `&foo` into RAX**.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table.  Often this is followed by `mov (%rax), %eax` or similar to actually get the value of a global variable like `int foo;`, in a shared library where our definition of the symbol may not be the one the main executable is using.  (See Thiago Macieira's blog: [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20171111043629/http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/) from 2012; it pre-dates `gcc -fno-plt`, and also predates [PIE executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux), but the situations for shared libraries accessing global variables hasn't improved.)

Normally you'd only ever use `foo@GOTPCREL(%rip)` for a global variable address [in a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587313/why-use-the-global-offset-table-for-symbols-defined-in-the-shared-library-itself), not an executable (not even a PIE executable).  Compilers assume that the main executable's global vars won't be "shadowed" by symbol interposition.  (In a shared library, you can [give symbols "hidden" ELF visibility so compilers will access them directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423294/how-to-access-a-c-global-variable-through-got-in-gas-assembly-on-x86-64-linux), knowing they won't participate in symbol interposition.)

**For `int foo`, just `mov foo(%rip), %eax` to load it or `lea foo(%rip), %rdi` to take its address without going through the GOT.**

---

But for function calls, if you want a pointer to a library function like `sin`, you can certainly get the final address in libm itself from loading a pointer from `sin@GOTPCREL`, instead of just taking a pointer to its PLT stub with `mov $sin, %edi` (and letting the linker rewrite sin to sin@plt when the symbol isn't found in anything you're statically linking, only a shared lib).  GCC's choice of which do use depends on how you're compiling.  (PIE vs. traditional position-dependent, and/or `-fno-plt` or not.)  [Unexpected value of a function pointer local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760086/unexpected-value-of-a-function-pointer-local-variable)

Or like `gcc -fno-plt` mode, call library functions with `call *sin@gotpcrel(%rip)` to use an indirect call through its GOT entry, basically inlining almost the same thing the PLT stub would, and forcing early binding instead of lazy (resolve the GOT entries at startup, instead of on first call.)

The NASM equivalent is `call [rel printf wrt ..got]`.

---

Note that `foo(%rip)` [uses the relative offset from here to the `foo` label/symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy), not adding its absolute address to the end of this instruction like you might guess, or like `123(%rip)` does.  But the
PCREL part of GOTPCREL is clearly referring to a PC-relative offset to the GOT entry from here.

---

Similar to @gotpcrel, you can do stuff like `call printf@plt` to explicitly call a function through a PLT entry.  I didn't find @gotpcrel documented in the GNU `as` manual, unfortunately.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/.